# How can I notify the user every time the site updates the products retrieved from the url link?

Tags: typescript, firebase, react-native, push-notification, notifications

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU7p0.png)
I pull the data from the URL link with the parse method and I can show it in the application and when it is updated, new products also appear. My wish is that every time the site is updated, the user should be notified about the new product. How can I do this without using Firebase? Please help!!
Click the png image to see code

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Aside from that, it sounds like you want to notify the user when something interesting happens in your Firebase project, which is one of the top use-cases for Cloud Functions and Cloud Messaging. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens